# Play Framework 2.x - @ManyToOne Relation just won't work with my view form

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework, many-to-one

I'm new to java play framework and also web app programming. At the beginning i was really amazed by the framework, but i have been struggling with creating a unidirectional manyToOne connection for a week now (!) and it's getting really frustrating.

I will show you my database creating statements, as well as my java models and my view, and i really hope you can help me further to finally make this work. I tried all the annotations that are available (like @JoinColumn etc.) but not one combination of annotations worked. Maybe one of the mistakes is the fact, that I'm creating the foreign-key-column inside the many-table on my own??? I don't know...

This is the final state from 15 minutes ago, I have not enough energy to try another one without some advice of you experts.

(just some basic info: every "specific exam" belongs to exactly one "general exam". I'd like to have it unidirectional, which means, I do not need to store anything about the relation in the general exam, but only in the specific exam.)

DATABASE CREATION:

```
# --- !Ups

# TABLES - general:

create table generalExam (
  id                      integer       not null       AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name                    varchar(45)   not null,
  is_deleted              boolean       not null       default false,
  constraint pk_generalexam primary key (id)
)
;

create table specificExam (
  id                      integer       not null       AUTO_INCREMENT,
  generalExam_id          integer       not null,       // THIS IS THE FOREIGN KEY COLUMN!!!!
  name                    varchar(45)   not null,
  constraint pk_specificexam primary key (id)
)
;
```

JAVA MODELS:

```
package models;

import com.avaje.ebean.Page;
import play.data.validation.Constraints;
import play.db.ebean.Model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Created by ben on 08.08.2015.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "generalExam")
public class GeneralExam extends Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "generalExam")
    public List<SpecificExam> specificExam;

}
```

... and ...

```
package models;

import com.avaje.ebean.Page;
import play.data.validation.Constraints;
import play.db.ebean.Model;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Created by ben on 08.08.2015.
 */

@Entity
@Table(name = "specificExam")
public class SpecificExam extends Model {

    /* --- VARIABLES ---*/

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "generalExam")
    public GeneralExam generalExam;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String name;

}
```

And finally
THE VIEW:

```
@(specificExamForm: Form[SpecificExam])

@import helper._

@implicitFieldConstructor = @{
    FieldConstructor(twitterBootstrapInput.render)
}

@main {

    <h1>Add a specific exam</h1>

    @form(routes.Exams.saveSpecificExam()) {

        <fieldset>
            @select(
                specificExamForm("generalExam.id"),
                options(GeneralExam.options),
                '_label -> "General Exam", '_default -> "-- Choose a general exam --", '_help -> "(every specific exam belongs to a general exam)",
                '_showConstraints -> false
            )
            @inputText(specificExamForm("name"), '_label -> "Specific Exam Name", '_help -> "")


        </fieldset>

        <div class="actions">
            <input type="submit" value="Add this specific exam" class="btn primary"> or
            <a href="@routes.Exams.listExams("specific")" class="btn">Cancel</a>
        </div>

    }

}
```

Just a little more information at the end:
As already mentioned, i've been trying many various combinations and some of the error messages i was getting were:

> [PersistenceException: ERROR executing DML bindLog[] error[Column
>   'name' "cannot be null"]]

and

> [PersistenceException: ERROR executing DML bindLog[] error[Column 'ID'
>   specified twice]]

***I just wanna say a BIG THANKS in advance, every help is very welcome, I couldn't get this running for over a week now -.-***

Comment: you posted GeneralExam model twice.

Comment: thank you, how embarrassing :D i just edited my post

Comment: If anyone has any tipps on how to solve this, I'd really appreciate it since I'm having a few vacation days the next two weeks and i'd really like to continue developing my app (my FIRST app :D )... but, well, i'm stuck at the moment -.-